# Limit Sprite kit Frame-rate

Tags: sprite-kit, frame-rate

I am new to programming and am creating a sprite kit game. I am making a scrolling background with a large image and this is lowering the frame rate to 30fps. However at the start of the game, before any other sprites are brought in, the frame rate varies between 30fps and 60fps. Because I am moving my background in the update method the speed the background scrolls at is constantly changing. I would like to limit the max frame rate to 30fps to achieve a constant speed. 
I have also heard about using Delta time to achieve a constant speed but have been unable to find tutorials about this online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you testing on a device? If not, do so, simulator performance is not the least bit representative of a real device

Comment: Tested on a device. Performance much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this by setting [frameInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/frameInterval) on you SKView to 2.

It will effectively lower your maximum frame rate from 60 to 30.

Answer (score 6):

frameInterval deprecated now.

Set [preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1642773-preferredframespersecond) property of your SKView object to 30.

**For Example (swift 3.2)** :

```
// ViewController.swift

    import Cocoa
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    class ViewController: NSViewController {

        @IBOutlet var skView: SKView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            if let view = self.skView {

                skView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30//this will set framerate to 30

                // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
                if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                    // Present the scene
                    view.presentScene(scene)
                }

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                view.showsFPS = true
                view.showsNodeCount = true
            }
        }
    }
```